# Springframework custom nested tag issue

Tags: spring, spring-bean

I am trying to create a custom XSD based configuration. I have custom tag which has another custom tag in turn. When parsing the inner tag, I get namespace handler not found. It could not locate handler class for http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans schema.

Sample XML:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:or="http://www.searsoutlet.com/schema/rest"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://www.mycompany.com/schema/rest http://www.mycompany.com/schema/rest-util-v1.0.xsd">

    <or:springRestTemplate id="customTemplateTest" >
        <or:basicAuth id="templateCreds" userName="restUser" password="restPassword" />
        <or:httpHeaders >
            <map>
                <entry key="headerName" value="headerValue" />
            </map>
        </or:httpHeaders>
    </or:springRestTemplate>

</beans>
```

Parser code:

```
@Override
    protected AbstractBeanDefinition parseInternal(Element element, ParserContext parserContext) {
        BeanDefinitionBuilder restTemplate = BeanDefinitionBuilder.rootBeanDefinition(SpringRestTemplateWithInterceptorsFactoryBean.class);

        List<Element> credentials = DomUtils.getChildElementsByTagName(element, AUTH_CHILD_ELEMENT);
        if (credentials != null && !credentials.isEmpty()) {
            restTemplate.addPropertyValue("basicAuth", parserContext.getDelegate().parseCustomElement(credentials.get(0)));
        }

        List<Element> httpHeadersElements = DomUtils.getChildElementsByTagName(element, HTTP_HEADER_CHILD_ELEMENT);
        if (httpHeadersElements != null && !httpHeadersElements.isEmpty()) {
            httpHeadersElements = DomUtils.getChildElementsByTagName(httpHeadersElements.get(0), "map");
        }

        if (httpHeadersElements != null && !httpHeadersElements.isEmpty()) {
            restTemplate.addPropertyValue("httpHeaders", parserContext.getDelegate().parseCustomElement(httpHeadersElements.get(0)));
        }

        return restTemplate.getBeanDefinition();
    }
```

I get error on this line:

```
restTemplate.addPropertyValue("httpHeaders", parserContext.getDelegate().parseCustomElement(httpHeadersElements.get(0)));
```

I tried to debug the issue. I see that parserContext has all Spring schema handlers loaded, expect for the beans schema.